# Trying to set up a exchanger formula in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm working on a spreadsheet which helps me reformat data to include certain criteria based on Intellectual Property.

In my excel I have column A which includes a Country that indexes to column L and M, L also listing Countries and M each countries individual way of formatting. Please see the example below:

[image: Extract from Excel]

As the image above shows, where the number in column B is "12345678" and the fetched format for US is 11/111,111 (the 1's are placeholders) that the formula I use doesn't input the special characters where they should go in the formula.

The value in column I that I am looking for would be "12/3345,678" not "12/456,8".

Please see the formula I use below:

```
=IF(E2<>"", LEFT(B2, FIND("/", E2) - 1) & "/" & MID(B2, FIND("/", E2) + 1, FIND(",", E2) - FIND("/", E2) - 1) & "," & MID(B2, FIND(",", E2) + 1, LEN(B2) - FIND(",", E2)), "")
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

PS. For other countries than the US, it could include Letters and more symbols than "/" and ",". Anything non-numerical more or less could be part of it, including spaces.

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in the question. You say you want the result to be `12/3345,678` but I think you have an extra `3` in there and the result you want is `12/345,678`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your pattern into a usable format string for the `TEXT` function:

```
=TEXT(B2,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"1","0"),",","\,"),"/","\/"))
```

Not sure what you want with the `10` ***Old number***.
If you want to show an error, you'll need to define what are valid and what are not valid.

[image]

If you might have other characters in your `Format`, but the `1` will always represent a digit, and anything else will be represented as itself, and if you have a `365` version, you can use the following:

```
=TEXT(
    B2,
    TEXTJOIN(
        "",
        TRUE,
        BYROW(
            MID(C2, SEQUENCE(LEN(C2)), 1),
            LAMBDA(a, SUBSTITUTE(a, a, IF(a = "1", "0", "\" & a)))
        )
    )
)
```

Which substitutes a `0` for any `1` and the literal character for anything else.

Comment: The above solves my problem for row 2, thank you so much.

The reason the 10 is there is to indicate that it would be a value in error meaning I need to make sure it tells me if the value in B has more or less numbers that what is dictated by C.

Comment: @StefanHögling Assuming the value in `B` will be all digits, just prefix the provided formula with something like: `IF(LEN(B2)<>(LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"1",""))), NA(), provided_formula )`. If you really need to return the `Value` error instead of the `NA()`, then replace `NA()` with something like `-"A"` which will generate that error.